# puppet epp conditional always evaluating to true

Tags: puppet

I'm using (open source) puppet 3.8.5 with future parser.

In an epp file, I say this:

```
<%= $telegraf_mysql %>
<%= $telegraf_mysql == true %>
<% if $telegraf_mysql == true { -%>
yes, my sql
<% } else { -%>
no
<% } -%>
```

If I set `$telegraf_mysql` to false, I see

```
false
false
no
```

But if I set `$telegraf_mysql` to true, I see

```
true
false
no
```

where I would have expected to see

```
true
true
yes, my sql
```

Any pointers?  Did I misunderstand the syntax?  Was the syntax different in 3.8 with future than in 4 but the docs I read didn't reflect that?

### Update

The value is being set in hiera thus:

```
telegraf:
  monitor_mysql: false
```

and then in puppet (.pp file) thus:

```
$telegraf = hiera('telegraf')
$telegraf_mysql = $telegraf['monitor_mysql']
```

Comment: How are you setting that value to true?

Comment: Note in particular that there is a tremendous difference between `$telegraf_mysql = true` and `$telegraf_mysql = 'true'`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Updated question to answer.  Does hiera always interpret that as text, I wonder...

Comment: Hiera supports booleans, and always has done so -- or at least, it is so documented.  But it is certainly worth verifying the type and value of your variable.  The stdlib module has functions that can help you verify data types and validate data values, and the `Notify` resource type and / or various functions (`info()`, `notice()`, ...) can help you emit the information discovered that way so that you can examine it more directly.

Comment: Thanks, that led me to the solution.  The types were correct in the .pp file but not in the .epp file.  But then I found that when I rendered the .epp, I said `'telegraf_mysql'         => "$telegraf_mysql",` instead of `'telegraf_mysql'         => $telegraf_mysql,`.  And those quotes coerced the boolean to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this:

```
# init.pp
class foo () {
  file { '/tmp/foo':
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp('foo/mytemplate.epp', {'telegraf_mysql' => false}),
  }
  file { '/tmp/bar':
    ensure  => file,
    content => epp('foo/mytemplate.epp', {'telegraf_mysql' => true}),
  }
}
include foo
```

and

```
# mytemplate.epp
<%= $telegraf_mysql %>
<%= $telegraf_mysql == true %>
<% if $telegraf_mysql == true { -%>
yes, my sql
<% } else { -%>
no
<% } -%>
```

then

```
$ bundle exec puppet -V
3.8.5
$ bundle exec puppet apply manifests/init.pp --modulepath=/Users/alexharvey/git/modules/ --parser=future 
...
$ cat /tmp/{foo,bar}
false
false
no
true
true
yes, my sql
```

then

```
$ PUPPET_GEM_VERSION=5.0.1 bundle update
...
$ bundle exec puppet apply manifests/init.pp --modulepath=/Users/alexharvey/git/modules/ 
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro-2.local in environment production in 0.07 seconds
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.03 seconds
```

(No changes applied.)